# Иногда метод срабатывает не корректно (Присваивание значений классам String и int в Java)

Tags: java

Вот код:

```
public void getWinnersTable(int[][] games) {
    //считаем очки команд
    int zenit = (games[0][0] * 3) + (games[0][1] * 2) + (games[0][2]);
    int spartak = (games[1][0] * 3) + (games[1][1] * 2) + (games[1][2]);
    int cska = (games[2][0] * 3) + (games[2][1] * 2) + (games[2][2]);

    //переменные для имён в таблице
    String first = "";
    String second = "";
    String third = "";

    //переменные для счёта победителя и др.
    int firstGoals = 0;
    int secondGoals = 0;
    int thirdGoals = 0;

    //сравниваем результат

    //победитель
    if (zenit > spartak && zenit > cska) {
        first = "Зенит";
        firstGoals = zenit;
    }
    if (spartak > zenit && spartak > cska) {
        first = "Спартак";
        firstGoals = spartak;
    }
    if (cska > zenit && cska > spartak) {
        first = "ЦСКА";
        firstGoals = cska;
    }

    System.out.println("На первом месте " + first + " c " + firstGoals + " очками.");

    //второе место
    if (zenit > spartak && zenit < cska || zenit < spartak && zenit > cska) {
        second = "Зенит";
        secondGoals = zenit;
    }
    if (spartak > zenit && spartak < cska || spartak < zenit && spartak > cska) {
        second = "Спартак";
        secondGoals = spartak;
    }
    if (cska > zenit && cska < spartak || cska < zenit && cska > spartak) {
        second = "ЦСКА";
        secondGoals = cska;
    }

    System.out.println("На втором месте " + second + " c " + secondGoals + " очками.");

    //третье место
    if (zenit < spartak && zenit < cska) {
        third = "Зенит";
        thirdGoals = zenit;
    }
    if (spartak < zenit && spartak < cska) {
        third = "Спартак";
        thirdGoals = spartak;
    }
    if (cska < zenit && cska < spartak) {
        third = "ЦСКА";
        thirdGoals = cska;
    }

    System.out.println("На третьем месте " + third + " c " + thirdGoals + " очками.");

}
```

Проблема в том, что код работает нормально почти всегда, то есть 5 раз я получаю все результаты, а на 6й такой ответ:

```
На первом месте  c 0 очками.
На втором месте  c 0 очками.
На третьем месте ЦСКА c 7 очками.
```

То есть - все результаты считаются, но переменным не присваиваются значения. Почему?

Метод может 10 раз отработать нормально, а на 11 выдать одно или несколько пустых значений. Неужели в коде ошибка?

Comment: Почему вы пишете if...if...if? Допустим проверяется первое условие, и оно true, и теоритически все остальные условия должны возвращать false. Но компилятор этого не знает, и он будет проверять и остальные условия. Советую использовать конструкцию if...else if...else if.
Так же можно для чистоты кода определять переменные first second third без значения.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, просто изначально планировалась другая конструкция, но на сонную голову очень туго соображается и всё превратилось в ЭТО :)

Answer (score 3):

У вас использованы строгие операторы сравнения и при равных значениях они буду давать - **ложь** (**false**).

Если вызвать ваш метод вот так

```
int[][] games = {
        {1,0,0},
        {1,0,0},
        {0,0,1},
};
getWinnersTable(games);
```

То результат будет вот такой:

```
На первом месте  c 0 очками.
На втором месте  c 0 очками.
На третьем месте ЦСКА c 1 очками.
```

При вычислении победителя и второго места ни одно условие не будет выполнено. Так как переменные `zenit` и `spartak` будут содержать равные значения, но большие чем в переменной `cska`.